# How to pass datetime format from c# to database correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a variable of **Datetime** in my model

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")]
    public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
```

and try to use bootstrap3 datetimepicker to pick a date and time in the view and then save it to database.

The controller is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXiPh.png)

Now everything works fine except the date it saves in the database is not the date I picked in the view.

For example, I'm picking 10/09/2017 1:58 AM in the view. As you can see, the month is October and the day is 9th.

[image: Datetimepicker screenshot]

But after I submitted, the value I got in database is 2017-09-10 01:58:00. And when I tried to use this value to compare with current date time, I found this
[image: Debugger screenshot].

The month became 9 and the day became 10.

The script looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#Deadline').datetimepicker({ minDate: moment(), format: format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss' });
});
</script>
```

I spent hours but still can't find out what's going on behind this problem. Please help me and thank you in advance for any advice or suggestion.

Comment: Your text and the picker view don't match. Please read your question again. Culture may also matter here, but it's unclear.

Comment: How is the date passed to the database? Because this the really relevant part.

Comment: Indeed - you haven't shown any database-related code at all. Are you sure the problem is in that part rather than getting the date from the browser to the server?

Comment: Sorry for not providing sufficient information. I've added my controller, I think it works as binding the input into an object and then save the object into the database. This is mostly auto generated code, I modified it a little to do my work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I still don't know what happens when passing value from view to database.

However I do found that the HtmlHelper I used for Deadline field is **EditorFor()**, and it rendered this field into type **datetime**. So no matter what format I specified in data annotation or in javascript, it always displays MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM(/PM) in that textbox, and falsely saves the value into database.

Now, I add @type = "text" into EditorFor() so that it will be rendered as type text. Or use TextBoxFor() instead of EditorFor().

It now looks like:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Deadline, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control"} })
```

Now it does what I expect it to do.